# How to validate any item entry which is already exist in firebase database in angular 6

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

![I have a table in the firebase database named unit and under the unit I have some childcare which you can see below in the pictures. now my problems is the if user entry some unit name like:Kg, Ltr, etc. if user enters Kg so it should validate with already exist and user would not able to submit it because he/ she is entering exist unit name which already exists in firebase database.and if he/she enters a unique unit name  only then they will able to submit it. but I have coded some code for this and it is not working fine when I add this validation inside my validation and when run the project and want to type a unique unit name but submit button is not appearing.
Please help me with this.
firebase table picture:]

[image]

here is my  .ts file where coded for this

[image]

and here the picture is when I run the project and type a unique unit name

[image]

we have imported this time here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE3yl.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please comment or give feedback on answer, accept if it worked for you so others can benefit

Comment: Please I need to fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

I would try implementing a database rule, something like this

```
"unit": {
   "$unit_id": 
   {
      ".validate": "$unit_id.child('unitname').child(newData.val()).exists() != true",
      }
   }
```

Comment: are you familiar with firebase  database.?

Comment: I have coded like this:
export class CustomValidator{
static unitname (afs:AngularFirestore){
  return (control:AbstractControl) =>{
    const unitname =control.value.toLowerCase();
    return afs.collection('unit', ref => ref.where('unitname', '==', unitname ))
    .valueChanges().pipe(
      debounceTime(5000),
    take(10),
    map(arr => arr.length ? {unitnameAvailable: false}:null ),
    )
  }
}
  }